# Unable to find Dateformat

Tags: java, date, datetime

I know this is a very silly question but I'm unable to find a suitable dateformatter for the given Date: `2020/04/01T20:00-05:00` or `2020/03/05T21:45-07:00`. Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why `/` not `-`? You should just use ISO 8601.

Comment: What did your search turn up? What have you tried? The question itself isn’t silly, but posting without reporting your search and research — it doesn’t give us the best starting point for helping you, and it’s against [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find one because that is a non-standard format. `-` is industry standard, using timezone offsets is outdated. Thus, you'd have to make it yourself. But this is quite simple, fortunately!

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd'T'HH:mmZZZZZ");
var zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2020/04/01T20:00-05:00", dtf);
System.out.println(zdt);
> 2020-04-01T20:00-05:00
```

Comment: What do you mean *using timezone offsets is outdated*? I consider them quite appropriate for some purposes, of course inappropriate for others. ISO 8601 uses them.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, there are times (heh) that offsets are the right answer, but more usually a zone id does everything you needed and more. A tzoffset based time cannot be used to do things like 'repeat this appointment next month' in a useful fashion (in which scenario is just adding 1 month and staying in that tzoffset the right move if the underlying zone where the appointment was made did a daylight savings switch in between?) tzoffsets don't require an entire tzdata source, but on modern platforms (including the JVM), tzdata is just available, so use that.